# API Gateway with Custom Domain Name Returning 403 Unless Host Header Defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are getting 403s (forbidden) from API Gateway when we use a custom domain name (public API). However, if we add the host header to the request which points to the AWS invoke URL it works fine. The customer has stated that this is unsatisfactory as they do not want to pass the host header, which makes sense since it seems pointless using a custom domain name if the host has to be specified.

Therefore, is there a way to make this work without setting the host header? The only header we use currently is for the API key (x-api-key).

For context, the environment consists of a REST API that triggers a Lambda function within a VPC.

Grateful for any support on this, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Private API or Regional/Edge API?

Comment: It’s a regional API.

Comment: Managed to find the solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897421/aws-api-gateway-lambda-custom-domain-route53-missing-authentication-token